# File Editing Automation

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna rename only two files from a folder using macro, Although there are lots files in that folder, but unable to do it. I wanna rename file name from "N2" to "NORTH 2 (UP/UK)" and "N3" to "NORTH 3 (HR/PB)". Also, I need to rename all values in first column named "zone", "from "N2" to "NORTH 2 (UP/UK)" and "N3" to "NORTH 3 (HR/PB)" using dynamic range of first column in each file.

I wish to just click on a button, and this task want to automate. Compiler automatically renames files, open each file one by one and replace existing zone values as per above condition and save the changes.

Question: How to assign dynamic range to below code
**.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1)**

Please see following code:

Getting run-time error 53 while trying to rename file

```
 Option Explicit

Sub FileOpen_Macro()
    Dim FileName(0 To 1) As String
    Dim ReplaceName(0 To 1) As String
    Dim ReplaceZoneName(0 To 1) As String
    
    'Dim FileName As String
    
    
    Const MyPath As String = "D:\iWork\Dunning Report\Dec'21\Result\"
    Dim strNewName As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    FileName(0) = "N2"
    FileName(1) = "N3"
    
    ReplaceName(0) = "North-2(UPUK).xlsx"
    ReplaceName(1) = "North-3(HRPB).xlsx"
    
    ReplaceZoneName(0) = "NORTH 2 (UP/UK)"
    ReplaceZoneName(1) = "NORTH 3 (HR/PB)"
    
    For i = 0 To 1
       
       'strNewName = Replace(FileName(i), "N", ReplaceName(i))
       strNewName = Replace(FileName(i) & ".xlsx", FileName(i) & ".xlsx", ReplaceName(i))
       Name MyPath & FileName(i) & ".xlsx" As MyPath & ReplaceName(i)
      With Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyPath & strNewName)
          ' Replace the cell A1 of the first sheet.
          .Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = Replace(.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1), FileName(i), ReplaceZoneName(i))
          'and Save & close
          .Close SaveChanges:=True
       End With
       MsgBox strNewName
       
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with your code?  FYI if you want to rename a file you can use `Name` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: Getting run-time error 53

Comment: Is `/` valid in a file Name?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

Comment: As far as I concern by your shared post that it is not feasible to rename file as per the value specified in my code. But, dear I am having to stuck only on this... Because our IT team specified this name in their database and my seniors are not ready to change it. Thus, in-order to routine activity easier, I am seeking help of Macro. Although, this just a minor part of my project. I have already made my project automated by maximum extent. Please see if it is possible to achieve this as well , else I will have to do with manual approach only. Merry Christmas!

Comment: _I will have to do with manual approach only._ Even manually you cannot use a `/ ` in your filename

Comment: How to assign dynamic range in . worksheet(1).cells(2,1), I want to assign row number dynamically following loop....

Comment: FYI your IT group should be aware of restrictions on characters in file names...

Comment: Yes, Tim you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Range.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace) to update all cells in a range.

```vb
Sub Replace_Macro()

    Const MyPath As String = "D:\iWork\Dunning Report\Dec'21\Result\"
    Dim sOld as string, sNew as string, sZone As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, ar(1)
    
    ar(0) = Array("N2", "North-2(UPUK)", "NORTH 2 (UP/UK)")
    ar(1) = Array("N3", "North-3(HRPB)", "NORTH 3 (HR/PB)")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
    
        sOld = ar(i)(0) & ".xlsx"
        sNew = ar(i)(1) & ".xlsx"
        sZone = ar(i)(2)
    
        ' check file exists
        If Dir(MyPath & sOld) <> "" Then
            With Workbooks.Open(MyPath & sOld)
                With .Sheets(1)
                    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    ' update column A
                    .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Replace _
                      What:=ar(i)(0), Replacement:=sZone, _
                      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                      MatchCase:=True
                End With
                ' save as new name
               .SaveAs FileName:=MyPath & sNew
               .Close False
            End With
             ' delete old file
            If Dir(MyPath & sNew) <> "" Then
                Kill MyPath & sOld
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox MyPath & sOld & " does not exist", vbCritical
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is there need of deleting file?   ' delete old file
            If Dir(MyPath & sNew) <> "" Then
                Kill MyPath & sOld
            End If

Comment: @Ravindra Do you want to keep the files N2.xlsx and N3.xlsx ?

Comment: Okay I got it... Also I just want to replace value in first column named zone not in entire column. For an instance, if any cell has value N2 in 3rd column then it should not replace that name.

Comment: @Ravindra By  3rd column do you mean Column C, code `.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Replace` only replaces values in column A

Comment: Thanks a lot...you are such a brilliant person. God bless you.

Comment: Although the solution provided by CDP1802 is perfect. But, just for knowledge I would like to know how to assign dynamic range in .worksheets(1).cells(2,1) rownumber should be passed dynamically whereas column. No remains fixed

Comment: How to make autofit column in the solution provided by - CDP1802

Comment: @Ravindra add `.Columns(1).AutoFit` after `.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Replace`

Comment: Wow....it is perfect